# Scroll between sections when progress finished

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Using `html+css+JS+Bootstrap`, I have some progress bar that when finished I would like to scroll down to a new section of the site.

Say I need this structure :

[image]

Where **no matter what screen used (mobile/desktop) section1 cover all the visible screen, same for 2.**

When the progress finishes (in JS) I would like to scroll to section2.

1. How would I divided my screen to sections using `html` ?
2. How would I scroll in JS when progress is done ?
3. Is there a way to set an anchor point to scroll there and leave html as is ?

---

Good practice : my js progress bar code is in file `manager.js`, when this progress finished I would like to call a function in another js file to scroll down(to make things clean). How technically do I call a function in another js file ? can I use delegate? how its done in this environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to style the sections using css. If you want them to always take 100% of the viewport height use:
`height: 100vh;` for that fun.
Just wrap the sections in a div each and apply the height to a class both wrappers share. As for width, if you haven't edited the body width it should be 100% by default, if so just apply `width: 100%` to the same class as well. As percentages are calculated from the parent's size, this only applies if your body covers the entire width.

Bootstrap's progressbar has a callback called 'done' attach a function to it which uses scrollIntoView

Progressbar:
https://www.javascripting.com/view/bootstrap-progressbar

ScrollIntoView:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView